# Route individual devices on router through VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

I have a Netgear Nighthawk R7000 and I would like to route a device through a VPN while letting the others just go through the ISP as normal. Is this possible to do without flashing the router? I don't know what to search for to find info unfortunately, so I can't really find info on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes

Generally speaking, if you install a VPN client on one of your computers, it will work without you having to modify your router, and your other computers will still go through the ISP as normal.

[OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/) is a pretty popular VPN client.  You can use it with OpenVPN providers (like [PIA](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/), for example.)  They usually give you the settings you need to tell your client to connect.

## VPN on Router

If you want the VPN on the router itself, then it gets more tricky.

The Nighthawk [apparently](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/R7000.aspx#tab-techspecs) to support OpenVPN to some extent:

> Now with OpenVPN Connect app on iOS and Android, securely access your
>   home network from your mobile device.

But if that's not enough for what you want, you'll probably need to flash the router with [tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) or something like that.

## VPN Gateway

There's also probably some way to set up a small computer (like a raspberry pi) with OpenVPN and tell the SmartTV to go through that instead of the router.

You'd have to enable ip forwarding on the pi, and somehow tell your smart tv that the pi should be its gateway to the Internet.

Comment: hmm. I guess I should have been more clear. This device can't really have a client installed. (smart TV) so that's why I was hoping to control it on the router side of things

Comment: @Mxracer888 I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With another router, plug it into your main router. Plug your device into new router and configure new router to use VPN.